# ¿Es obligatorio llamar al constructor de la clase base desde el constructor de una clase heredada de esta?

Tags: java, poo, herencia, constructor

Mi problema es el siguiente, al heredar de una clase (Base, ya sea abstracta o no) la cual tiene uno o más constructores definidos explícitamente me veo obligado a llamar alguno de ellos en cualquier constructor que defina de la clase derivada porque si no lo hago me manda un mensaje de error.

Por otro lado, si intento llamar al constructor por defecto desde la clase derivada y éste no está definido explícitamente por mí, también me manda error.

Quiero saber por qué no llama constructor por defecto cuando este está implícito en el código y también si es obligatorio llamar a los constructores desde las clases derivadas.

Comment: *Debo aclarar que esto solo sucede cuando la clase base tiene algún constructor*... Esa afirmación es motivo de confusión para ti. No existe ninguna clase que no tenga constructor, todas tienen uno, cuando no lo declaras, se declara [un constructor por defecto implícitamente](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9). Creo que debes [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/141061/edit), dando más detalles sobre el contexto y los fragmentos de código de tu error ya que se trata de eso, de un error en tu contexto más que de un problema de constructor.

Comment: Disculpa se me pasó por alto, ya realicé la edición.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando se crea un objeto en Java se realizan las siguientes operaciones de forma automática:

1. Se asigna memoria para el objeto.
2. Se inicializan los atributos de ese objeto con los valores predeterminados por el sistema.
3. Se llama al constructor de la clase.

Nota: si para una clase no se define ningún método constructor **se crea uno automáticamente por defecto**.

El **constructor por defecto** es un constructor sin parámetros que no hace nada. Los atributos del objeto son iniciados con los valores predeterminados por el sistema.

Ejemplo:

```
public Class Persona {

    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;

    // Cero constructor

}

public Class MainPersona {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Persona persona = new Persona();

        // Se llama al constructor por defecto

    }
}
```

Un constructor por defecto (vacío) luce de la siguiente forma:

```
// Constructor vacío
public Persona() {
}
```

Cuando instancias una clase, la clase padre debe tener por obligación al menos un constructor, aunque sea vacío, pero debe tener uno. Si no lo tiene, recibirás el error:

> The constructor Persona() is undefined

Entonces, para solucionar este error debes tener el constructor vacío de la siguiente forma:

```
public Class Persona {

    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;

    /*
     * Constructor vacío
     * Evita el error "The constructor Persona() is undefined"
     * cuando se instancia esta clase en alguna otra clase
     */
     public Persona() {
         super();
     }

}
```

Si necesitas otro constructor en la clase padre, puedes tenerlo, puedes tener la cantidad de constructores que necesites, ejemplo:

```
public Class Persona {

    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;

    /*
     * Constructor vacío
     * Evita el error "The constructor Persona() is undefined"
     * cuando se instancia esta clase en alguna otra clase
     */
     public Persona() {
         super();
     }

     // Constructor
     public Persona(String nombre, String apellido) {
         super(); // Llama al constructor vacío primero
         this.nombre = nombre;
         this.apellido = apellido;
     }

}
```

Espero haberte ayudado!.

Comment: Excelente explicación amigo, gracias por tomarte tu tiempo de explicarlo con un trozo de código, de verdad me salvaste.

Saludos!

Comment: Estamos para ayudarte amigo. Si mi respuesta fue tu solución, no olvides seleccionarla como Respuesta Elegida. Cualquier duda que tengas, a tu orden.

Answer (score 4):

Cuando existe herencia en Java, y la clase padre no tiene constructor por defecto, es obligatorio llamar explícitamente al constructor de la clase padre desde el constructor de la clase hija.

Te explico un poco los conceptos:

Todas las clases en Java tienen que tener al menos un constructor, aunque no lo declares explícitamente. Ese constructor es llamado constructor por defecto y es equivalente a declarar un constructor que no reciba parámetros. Ahora, si no es declarado explícitamente, el compilador lo agrega por ti en tiempo de compilación, esto garantiza que todas las clases tengan al menos un constructor en Java.

Unido a lo anterior tenemos algo muy parecido. Si una clase tiene un padre, cuando se invoca al constructor de esta, se tiene que invocar primero al constructor de la clase padre.

Para llamar al constructor de la clase padre debemos utilizar la siguiente sentencia `super()` (sin parámetros en caso de llamar al constructor por defecto). Esta tiene que ser la primera linea dentro del código del constructor de la clase hija (excepto si en vez de `super()` utilizamos `this()`, donde estaríamos llamando a otro constructor de la misma clase hija, pero dentro de este otro constructor la primera linea tiene que ser la llamada al `super()`).

Al igual que pasa con el constructor por defecto, si nosotros omitimos esta linea en nuestro código, el compilador la agrega en tiempo de compilación, pero intentará invocar al constructor por defecto de la clase padre. Por esto, si la clase padre no tiene un constructor por defecto, tenemos que declarar explícitamente en el constructor de la clase hija, la llamada al constructor correspondiente de la clase padre.

Se que puede parecer un enredo pero he tratado de explicarlo lo más sencillo posible.

Comment: creo que a tu respuesta, que por cierto esta completamente correcta, le hace falta codigo de ejemplo

Comment: Ocurre que poner código de byteCode, que es cómo único se pueden ver estas cosas, sería un poco engorroso. Pero cualquiera que desee probar diferentes variantes solo debe revisar el bytecode generado por el compilador.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación.

Saludos!